# Ionic: Unit test service using SQLite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, unit-testing, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an hybrid app using Ionic. I'm using Ionic 2 but my question is not really related to this specific version, it's more about the best approach to this problematic.

I'm using SQLite to store the data I need. I have a service who reads and writes data into database and process these data.

I would like to unit test this service. I know how to run unit tests with Karma and Jasmine and inject services in it, but I'm a bit confused about the SQLite part.

I've written a DB service who connects to database and create the tables I need.
I would like to test the functions firing the queries, test the format of data retrieved and some other functions using data retrieved from database.

So, should I mock functions executing the queries and test only the ones who process these data? Or is there a way to inject my DB service to get real queries executed?

BTW, as tests with Karma are ran into a browser, the Cordova SQLite plugin doesn't work so I need to mock SQLite somehow. I've read that we could use WebSQL instead to run the tests, but got no success so far.

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: You have to use WebSQL in the browser